# Blanking out form elements?

Tags: html, css

I often form elements that are blanked out (e.g. the content is un-editable, you can't focus, gray overlay). What styling or attribute is applied to the form elements to create this effect?

Any answers will be very much appreciated :).

Comment: disabled="1" / or just disabled. e.g. <input disabled="1" ...

Comment: Oh sweet. Want to post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: For the greyed-out look use `disabled`, but you can also use `readonly` to prevent user-interaction: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yYeR/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabled="1" / or just disabled. e.g. `<input disabled="1" ...`

Answer (score 0):

The form element is disabled;

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

you create a disabled input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" disabled="disabled" />
```

This also works for all other form elements except elements with `type='hidden'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the disabled attribute:

- [HTML button disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp)
- [HTML input disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

> The disabled attribute specifies that a button should be disabled.
>
> A disabled button is unusable and un-clickable.
>
> The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from clicking on the
>   button until some other condition has been met (like selecting a
>   checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript is required to remove the disabled
>   value, and make the button usable.

The syntax use is:

```
<button disabled="disabled">
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there is disabled to create the grey overlay

```
<input disabled type="text" name="myInput">
```

and readonly to make it focus but uneditable

```
<input readonly type="text" name="myInput">
```